# GNOME Vs Budgie

Tags: gnome, budgie

I am thinking of changing my DE from GNOME to Budgie. I use Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, and might upgrade to 20.04 in a few days.

I have heard that Budgie consumes less RAM compared to GNOME. Does it also consume less power? My [Dell Inspiron 15R 5537](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/inspiron-15r-5537/docs) laptop lasts only about 1.5 hours when charged to 100%.

Answer (score 1):

This chart from [an article at Ubuntubuzz](https://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2019/07/comparison-of-memory-usages-of-ubuntu-1904-and-flavors-in-2019.html) shows, at idle with no apps loaded, Budgie uses 40 MB (4 %) less RAM than GNOME.

[image: chart comparing idle memory use of different desktops]

Once apps are loaded, the relative advantage of Budgie may change, for causes described at  [https://unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/586003/find-the-lightest-desktop-environment).

I am not aware of a power consumption comparison of different desktops. However, you may wish to consider looking into [tlp](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/tlp?tab=Votes) and other packages dedicated to [lower battery consumption](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/power-management). That would be the subject of another question, as [your questions should be reasonably scoped](https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask).

Since different hardware has different power management capabilities, if you have [power management](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/power-management) questions, please specify the make of laptop, and its model part number (found on the serial number sticker on most laptops); "model" numbers elsewhere on laptops are generally marketing buzzwords and do not help us find the hardware manuals.